# How can I create a type with multiple parameters in OCaml?

Tags: types, polymorphism, ocaml

I'm trying to create a type that has multiple type parameters.  I know how to make a type with one parameter:

```
type 'a foo = 'a * int
```

But I need to have two parameters, so that I can parameterize the 'int' part.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way to do this is:

```
type ('a, 'b) foo = 'a * 'b
```

Type parameters aren't curried, so you need to provide them in tuple form as a single parameter.  A good example of this is the Hashtbl module:

> ```
> type ('a, 'b) t
> ```
>
> The type of hash tables from type 'a
>   to type 'b.

Answer (score 2):

`# type ('a, 'b) couple = 'a * 'b ;;`

For instance...